# How to fix "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors" using ionic 4 and ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've imported ng2-pdf-viewer and set it up as per the example, but I get the "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:" error.

I've tried moving the import to the home.ts, but that didn't work either.  I really need to figure this out.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, PdfViewerModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    PdfViewerModule,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      NG2-PDF-VIEWER
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <pdf-viewer src="{{pdf}}" original-size="true" show-all="true"></pdf-viewer>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  providers: [ ]
})
export class HomePage {

  public pdf;
  constructor() {
    this.pdf = 'http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf';
  }

}
```

This is the full error I am getting:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'pdf-viewer'.
1. If 'pdf-viewer' is an Angular component and it has 'src' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pdf-viewer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

<ion-content>
  <pdf-viewer [ERROR ->]src="{{pdf}}" original-size="true" show-all="true"></pdf-viewer>
</ion-content>
"): ng:///HomePageModule/HomePage.html@9:14
'pdf-viewer' is not a known element:
1. If 'pdf-viewer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pdf-viewer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

<ion-content>
  [ERROR ->]<pdf-viewer src="{{pdf}}" original-size="true" show-all="true"></pdf-viewer>
</ion-content>
"): ng:///HomePageModule/HomePage.html@9:2
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'pdf-viewer'.
1. If 'pdf-viewer' is an Angular component and it has 'src' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pdf-viewer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

<ion-content>
  <pdf-viewer [ERROR ->]src="{{pdf}}" original-size="true" show-all="true"></pdf-viewer>
</ion-content>
"): ng:///HomePageModule/HomePage.html@9:14
'pdf-viewer' is not a known element:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import this module (PDF viewer) exactly into the module that is to use its components.

You have it at app.module.ts but you need to import it by the module that uses it